# Karate: Sub feature with multiple sceanrios does not execute all scenarios in case of failure

Tags: karate

I am using 0.7.0 version of Karate. I am trying to data drive tests. For that I have a Driver feature which has a scenario in the following format:

```
Feature: Driver feature
Scenario: MainSceanrio
* table inputParams
 ......
 ......
* call read (calledFeature.feature) inputParams
```

The calledFeature.feature contains multiple scenarios - each working on same input params - but testing out slightly differnt functionality/sceanrio.
This is how calledFeature.feature looks like:

```
Feature: Called feature.

Sceanrio: Scenario1
#create req using input param and few custom settings
# verify response is according to input param

Sceanrio: Scenario2
#create req using input param and few custom settings
# verify response is according to input param

Sceanrio: Scenario3
#create req using input param and few custom settings
# verify response is according to input param
```

Now , if Scenario2 fails, Scenario3 does not get executed and control falls to next iteration of table MainScenario (driver feature).

Is there a way to execute all scenarios of called feature file irrespective of failures.

PS: If instead of calling calledFeature.feature from Driver Feature,if I use Java class something like below:

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:rest/karate/calledFeature.feature")
public class DummyCaller {}
```

And replace all parameterization from calledFeature.feature with static values, It executes all sceanrios even if some of them fails.

How to enable call read(feature) to execute all scenarios of called feature despite of failures. (or am I missing something)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the same as this bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/421

Which is fixed in the RC version, it would be great if you try 0.8.0.RC8 and let me know if it solves this problem.